# Sorting the results of a procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am executing:

```
exec sp_who 
go
```

Is it possible to sort by a field like this?

```
exec sp_who order by dbname
go
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Nothing says "I'm a guy" like having a username like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using OPENROWSET as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure).

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

SELECT * INTO #MyTempTable FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=(local)\SQL2008;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'EXEC sp_who')

SELECT * FROM #MyTempTable order by [dbname]
```

If for whatever reason you are unable to use OPENROWSET then you will have to create a temp table that matches the output of `sp_who` exactly.

e.g

```
Create Table #temptable
(
spid smallint,
ecid smallint,
status varchar(100),
loginame varchar(100),
hostname varchar(100),
blk smallint,
dbname varchar(100),
cmd varchar(100),
request_id smallint
)

Insert Into #temptable
Exec sp_who

Select * From #temptable order by [dbname]
```

Answer (score 1):

If possible, the best solution would be to try and refactor the procedure into a view.

**EDIT**

You could also modify the procedure to stick the output into a temporary table, which you could then query.

If you are only going to sort by dbname, the the simplest solution would be to modify the procedure to always sort by dbname.

Comment: @i am a gir, it depends on the procedure code, some simple procures can be turned into a view, but most complex ones can't.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
exec sp_helptext sp_who
```

This will give you the SQL to use.  Copy this into a new query window and add in your `ORDER  BY` clause.